# Trigonometry and Vector Word Problem

Tags: trigonometry

You shoot off a toy rocket at an angle 20 degrees west of north while the wind is blowing east to west at 10 mph. The rocket's actual speed is (with the wind) is 64.11 mph. What is the actual direction of the rocket?

It seems necessary to know what the initial speed of the rocket is to solve this problem. Can anyone show me why it isn't and what the answer is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're given, velocity of wind:
$$v_w=-10\hat i\;\rm mph$$
velocity of rocket(let speed be x):
$$v_r=[x\cos(20^\circ)\hat i-x\sin(20^\circ)\hat j]\;\rm mph$$
 velocity of rocket with respect to wind: $$v_r-v_w=v_{r,w}=[(x\cos(20^\circ)+10)\hat i-x\sin(20^\circ)\hat j]\;\rm mph$$
And given that $|v_{r,w}|=64.11\;\rm mph$ can't you get x?:
$$[x\cos(20^\circ)+10]^2+[x\sin(20^\circ)]^2=64.11^2$$
solving:
$$x=54.62$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it.  Draw a ray out from the origin at an angle 20 degrees west of north.  Then draw a vector from the origin due east with a magnitude of 10.  Finally, from that spot 10 mph east of the origin, draw a circle with a radius of 64.11.  Where these intersect is the vector for your rockets velocity without wind.

Because at that point, if you were to go 10 mph back west, with the wind, you should be at a magnitude of 64.11 from the origin.

This should help you work out the trig involved.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What software did you use to create the above graph?

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/download